# Hard drive formatted by Windows 7 not recognized by Windows Server 2008

Tags: hard-drive, formatting

I have a new 3.5" 2 TB hard drive. Using a Windows 7 laptop + a docking station, I quick formatted it to NTFS. Next, I put this hard drive on a docking station that's hooked via eSata to a rack server -- Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. Now, the server can't see the drive. My Computer shows nothing new nor does the disk management tool. The server's dock works with other hard drives and this hard drive is also still usable by my laptop. Since the server doesn't see the drive, I can't even use the server to reformat it. How do I get this drive usable on the server?

BTW: Don't ask why this setup exists, it predates my employment here and I'm fighting to change it. For now though, it is what it is.

**Edit:**

Dock claims it can support up to 2 TB

Model: Thermaltake BlacX ST0005U: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817153071

Comment: What's the docking station model?

Comment: Any chance the dock is experiencing operational difficulties? Has another known working drive (with the dock) been used to ensure that the dock is actually working?

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible that your docking station doesn't support drives of 2TB. You should check the manufacturer's website to see if there is a firmware update for it, or at least to see the max size spec.